# Why does ToRules return a Sequence?

Tags: replacement, rule, language-design

Why does [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html) return a `Sequence` expression?  Why doesn't it return directly what `{ToRules[...]}` does now?  **In what application is having `Sequence` beneficial here?**

Now we have to do `x /. {ToRules[...]}` instead of `x /. ToRules[...]`.  I would have thought that this is the standard and most common application.

Examples:

```
ToRules[x == 1 || x == 2]
(* Sequence[{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}] *)

ToRules[x == 1]
(* {x -> 1} *)

ToRules[False]
(* Sequence[] *)

ToRules[True]
(* {} *)
```

Comment: ``Reduce`ReduceToRules`` returns a list.

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to do something like `ToRules /@ solutions`. That's the only time I can recall liking the `Sequence` return value.

Comment: Another value of Sequence is to insert several rules into a list without increasing the dimension of the list (avoiding the need for Flatten):   `mySeq = Sequence[c -> d, e -> f]; {a -> b, mySeq, c -> d}` yields {a -> b, c -> d, e -> f, c -> d}.  This can be quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

It is very old function. It was introduced in V1.0 in 1988. It was used in the following way:

[image]

So `Sequence` header *was* very useful. [Ref](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/3.4.html) (Section 3.4.2).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a way of letting you know that `ToRules` doesn't have an appropriate head to use for the conversion.  Or put another way when a head isn't supplied `Sequence` is used by default.  Consider:

```
Delete[{1, 2}, 0]

{1, 2} /. _[x__] :> x
```

> ```
> Sequence[1, 2]
>
> Sequence[1, 2]
> ```

`ToRules` converts `And` to `List`:

```
ToRules[a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 3]
```

> ```
> {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}
> ```

Perhaps it doesn't make sense to equate `List` with `Or` as well?